# Cannot find a file available in the same folder

Tags: php

I'm trying to read the content of `config.json` file which is available in the same folder of the file that read it, this file is called `settings.php`, I actually have this line of code in `settings.php`:

```
$jsonData = file('config.json');
```

the problem's that I get:

> Warning: file(config.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

this is weird because as you can see from the image:

[image]

I'm trying this app on localhost with mamp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is most likely because your settings.php is included by a index.php that's a directory higher.

Php file opening will always assume from the "parent" php file where execution started as base directory and not of the included files.

Try using [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

```
$jsonData = file(__DIR__.'/config.json');
```

> `__DIR__` The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to dirname(**FILE**). This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is the root directory.